# Count iterations of pandas dataframe apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to count how many times my database function runs.

My code looks like this

```
df = pd.read_csv("nodos_results3.csv")
df['URL_dashboard'] = df.apply(create_url, axis = 1)
df.to_csv('nodos_results4.csv', index = False)
```

I want to count how many times the function "create_url" runs.  If I was in C++, for example, I would simply have the function take in another input

```
create_url(database i_DB, int i_count)
{
//stuff I want done to database

i_count++;
}
```

but I'm not sure how to do something equivalent using pandas dataframe apply.

Update: For anyone who might find this while googling in the future - I personally didn't solve this issue.  I was moved to another project and didn't continue working on this.  Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: You C++ code won't do the counting because C++ passes parameters by value, not by reference.

Comment: Pretend I made it a pointer

Answer (score 1):

`apply` executes the function exactly once for each row. So, the function is executed `df.shape[0]` times. **Correction:** As per @juanpa.arrivillaga, `apply` executes the function twice on the first row, the correct answer is `df.shape[0]+1`.

Alternatively, create a global variable (say, `create_url_counter=0`) and increment it in the function body:

```
def create_url(...):
    global create_url_counter
    ...
    create_url_counter += 1
```

Be aware, though, that having global variables is in general a bad idea.

Comment: That works for when I'm only applying the function to one database, once. I want to be able to keep a count going when I apply the function multiple times, without having to do the arithmetic

Comment: Careful, `.apply` calls the function *twice* on the first row or column. You should **not use apply for side effects**. Just use a loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why so? Never heard of that. (But looks like indeed it does!)

Comment: According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) (check the Notes section) it's to decide whether or not to take an optimized path. This bit me in the past!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga "_In the current implementation_", yikes!